# Lightning record page dashboard component error

Tags: lightning-experience, dashboard

I have installed 'Force.com Sites Usage Reporting' app in my Org. This app contains 'Site Usage Dashboard' I've tried to refer this component to my lightning record page I am getting following error "Invalid dashboard Unique Name SiteUsageDashboard- no dashboards found". If I clone that dashboard and referred that dashboard in lightning experience it's working fine.

Does anyone help me on this issue?[image]

Comment: I guess the dashboard name is conflicting with some other name... can you try to change it and try... it is working if you clone it because it will have the unique name and will not conflict with other name..

Comment: @SagarHinsu I have queried my org all dashboard api name every dashboard has a unique name.

Comment: can you query the specific Dashboard in the image shown?

Comment: @SagarHinsu yes it's API name is unique